# Using facet_trelliscope without defining axis limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using `facet_trelliscope` from `trelliscopejs` this works:

```
library(trelliscopejs)
library(ggplot2)

x <- 1:10
y <- 1:10
group <- rep(c("A","B"),5)

df <- data.frame(group, x, y)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
  xlim(0, 10) + ylim(0, 10) +
  facet_trelliscope(~group)
```

But this doesn't:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + 
  facet_trelliscope(~group)
```

It throws up this error:

```
Error in scale_fn() : could not find function "scale_fn"
```

My question is, do axis limits always need to be defined for facet_trelliscope to work?

Comment: I don't get an error when running your code, try updating `ggplot2` or `trelliscopejs`

Comment: I don't get errors.

Comment: Hi would you like to show your session info? I think this is a version problem of `ggplot2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks both it was indeed a package error. If anyone sees the error in future just remove and re-install ggplot2.

Comment: This works with ggplot 2.2.1. However, this does not work with the latest development version 2.2.1.9000 of ggplot anymore. `scale_fn` is missing again. I [filed an issue](https://github.com/hafen/trelliscopejs/issues/48) on Github.